# How to return values using multiple wildcard inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to locate information regarding part numbers in a table. The challenge is in the table there are leading zeros in the table and not in the data that I'm using.

If I run the query with one value as show below it works and I'm given the information I need.

```
SELECT ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM   tblZMMGPNXREF
where ZMATNR like '%89187605%'
```

But when I use multiple values as show below I get this error

> " Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','."

```
SELECT ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM   tblZMMGPNXREF
where ZMATNR like '%89187605%','%89363059%'
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted syntax is clearly not supported.  You can use `OR`:

```
SELECT ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM tblZMMGPNXREF
WHERE ZMATNR like '%89187605%' OR ZMATNR like '%89363059%';
```

Or regular expressions:

```
SELECT ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM tblZMMGPNXREF
WHERE ZMATNR REGEXP '89187605|89363059';
```

Or, perhaps you don't need `LIKE` at all, and you can just use `IN`:

```
SELECT ZMATNR, ZLPN
FROM tblZMMGPNXREF
WHERE ZMATNR IN ('89187605', '89363059');
```

This is the best choice if it does what you want.

Comment: I need to use % because there are leading zeros in the table that are variable within the table. I have around 9,000 values i'm tying to use to get information for. Do you have any recommendations on how I can run the code for all of them?

Comment: @BrianToman . . . You should ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Strings of numbers with leading zeroes will be coerced to an integer value if you compare to an integer. Then the leading zeroes will not matter:

```
mysql> select '00001234' = 1234;
+-------------------+
| '00001234' = 1234 |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
```

But this only works if you compare to integers, not strings.

So Gordon Linoff's suggestion does not work:

```
WHERE ZMATNR IN ('89187605', '89363059');
```

But if you use integers, it should work:

```
WHERE ZMATNR IN (89187605, 89363059);
```